# Destroy AudioPlayer/Videoview when the view goes out of focus in RecycleView in Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to create a feed like Instagram where I want the view to stop playing the audio as soon as the user scrolls past it.

The second use case is to play audio from one source at a time.

As of now, if I play say 2 posts, both of them keep playing on different threads.

I have used a viewModel to get the data into an adapter where the component is rendered.

[image]

This is how my recyclerview looks and if Audio 1 is playing, And the user clicks on Video 1 the audio 1 should stop playing.

Secondly, if the Audio 1 view goes out of view, it should stop playing audio.

The code for my adapter class is as follows :

```
class PostListAdapter : PagedListAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(PostDiffUtilCallback()) 
{
@Inject
lateinit var  postsService: PostsService
    var playstate = false;



override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_post_v2, parent, false)
    return PostViewHolder(view)
}





init {
    DaggerApiComponent.create().inject(this)
}



override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val post = getItem(position)
    val view=holder.itemView
    val videoView = view.videoView1
    var con=view.context
    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    val seekBar = view.seekBar
    val play=view.play
    val audioView=view.audioPlayer
 
    media_link=post.media.toString()
  




    if(type is video) {
        //trigger video


        videoView.resizeMode=AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH

        try {
          
        
            val player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(con)
            videoView.setPlayer(player)
            // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
            val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory =
                DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                    con,
                    Util.getUserAgent(con, "Mehfil")
                )
            val uri = Uri.parse(
                media_link
            )

            val videoSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri)
// Prepare the player with the source.
           
            player.prepare(videoSource)

            // videoView.start()
        } catch (E: Exception) {
            Log.d("Video Error", E.toString())
        }
    }
   

    if( media type is audio) 
{

        imageView.visibility = View.GONE
        //audioPlayer.visibility = View.GONE
        audioView.visibility = View.VISIBLE




        if(post.media!!.indexOf("http:")!= -1)
            post.media=post.media!!.replace("http","https")


        mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener {

            if (it.isPlaying) {
                seekBar.max = mediaPlayer?.duration!!

            }


        }

        val mHandler = Handler()
//Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
        var mUpdateSeekbar: Runnable = (object : Runnable {

            override fun run() {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    val mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer!!.getCurrentPosition()
                    seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition)
                    Log.d("Current-duration", "" + mCurrentPosition)
                    //current_time.text=""+mediaPlayer!!.getCurrentPosition()/1000
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        })

        mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
            playstate = false;
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play2)
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateSeekbar);
            seekBar.setProgress(0)
            mediaPlayer!!.release()
            // current_time.text="End"

        }
        audioFrame.setOnClickListener {

            if(playCount==0)
            {


                var audioUrl: Uri = Uri.parse(post.media!!.toString())

                if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying)
                {
                    mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                    mediaPlayer!!.release()
                }


                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(con, audioUrl)
                seekBar.max = mediaPlayer?.duration!!
                Log.d("Max-duration", "" + mediaPlayer?.duration!!)



                playCount++;
            }
            if (!playstate) {
                mediaPlayer?.start()
                var audioId = mediaPlayer?.audioSessionId
                if (audioId != -1)
                    blast.setAudioSessionId(audioId!!);
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause2)
                playstate = !playstate
                mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbar, 1000)


            } else {
                mediaPlayer?.pause()
                // current_time.text="Pause"
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play2)
                playstate = !playstate
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateSeekbar);
            }


            // Seek bar change listener
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, i: Int, b: Boolean) {
                    if (b) {

                        mediaPlayer?.seekTo(i)
                    }
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                }
            })

        }
    }








}
```